# How do I add extra space in the edges of rounded border HTML table with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add some extra space at the edges of a rounded HTML Table. Here is a picture of what I want to achieve (Notice the extra space on the edges of the table):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAm64.jpg

For the extra space on the edges, I tried to add a border with the same colour as the inside, but for some reason, the rounded corners did not come.

 Here is my code:

```css
table{
  background-color: #FBF85D;
  border: 25px solid #FBF85D;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<table class="board" cellpadding="15px">
  <tr>
      <!-- I am using Bootstrap buttons -->
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use **Padding**

> Try This

```css
 
table{
  background-color: #FBF85D;
  border: 25px solid #FBF85D;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}


.btn-circle{
 padding:20px;
 outline:none;
 border:0;
 border-radius:60px;
}
```

```html
<table class="board" cellpadding="15px">
  <tr>
      <!-- I am using Bootstrap buttons -->
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-secondary btn-circle btn-circle-xl"></button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: :) And I THank You BEcause Ur Answer IS Very Clear